# Элементы последовательности

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите, какой из двух кодов более правильнее, или что можно переделать или дописать в коде.

1)

> Программа должна, выводить на экран первые 55 элементов последовательности
>   1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 ...

Первый код:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int sum = 1;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = sum; i <= 333; i += 2)
        {
            sum = i;
            count++;
            if (sum == 111)
                break;
            System.out.println (count + " элемент - " + sum);
        }
        System.out.println ("Первые " + (count - 1) + " элементов");
    }
}
```

Второй код:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = sum; i <= 54; i++) {
            sum = 2 * i + 1;
            count++;
            System.out.println(count + " элемент - " + sum);
        }
        System.out.println("Первые " + count + " элементов");
    }
}
```

2) Подскажите и по этому коду, что можно добавить или переделать.

> Программа должна, выводить на экран все неотрицательные элементы последовательности
>   90 85 80 75 70 65 60 ...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int first = 90;
        final int second = -90;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = first; i > second; i-=5) {
            count++;
            if(i == 0)break;
            System.out.println(count + " элемент - " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Все неотрицательные элементы 90 85 80 75 70 65 60 ….");
    }
}
```

3) Подскажите и по этому коду, что можно добавить или переделать.

> Программа должна, выводить на экран первые 20 элементов последовательности
>   2 4 8 16 32 64 128 ...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int a = 1;
        int sum;
        int count = 0;
        sum = (int) Math.pow(a,2);
        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            sum*=2;
            count++;
            System.out.println(count + " элемент - " + sum);
        }
        System.out.println("Первые " + count + " элементов");
    }
}
```

P.S. Все компилировал и запускался код, спрашиваю совет, что можно доделать или переделать как будет правильней.

Подскажите еще по коду.

> Вывести на экран все члены последовательности 2an-1–1, где a1=2, которые меньше 10000.

Вот написал код с циклом for вроде работает. Первый код

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        for(int a = 2, i = 1; i < a; a = 2 * a - 1,i++) {
            if(a <=10000) {
                System.out.print(a + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

С циклом for выводит вот так: 3 5 9 17 33 65 129 257 513 1025 2049 4097 8193

Второй код с циклом while.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        int a = 2;
        while(true) {
            if(a <= 10000) {
                a = 2 * a - 1;
                System.out.print(a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

С циклом while выводит вот так: 3 5 9 17 33 65 129 257 513 1025 2049 4097 8193 16385

Подскажите, как правильно написать с циклом while.

Подскажите по коду что не правильно не могу разобраться!
вроде бы все логически правильно

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []){
      for(int a = -166, i = 1; a > 9 && a < 100; a = 2 * a + 200, i++){
           System.out.println(a + " ");
       }
    }
}
```

Должен выводить, а Не выводит результат на экран все двузначные члены последовательности!

Comment: Голосую за закрытие, т.к. данный вопрос включает в себя несколько разных вопросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для первой задачи второй вариант с небольшими изменениями сгодится лучше. Второй вариант чуть менее эффективен, но зато он намного читабельнее. И в нём нет странного дополнительного условия выхода из цикла. И вообще вычисленные "магические" числа 111 и 333 - не гут.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []){
       int count = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i <= 54; i++) {
           int value = 2 * i + 1;
           count++;
           System.out.println(count + " элемент - " + value);
       }
       System.out.println("Первые " + count + " элементов");
   }
}
```

Второй код явно переделан из какого-то другого. Опять же, зачем вам -90, если вы внутри цикла явно проверяете на ноль? Почему бы внутри for не проверять на 0, а if выкинуть?

По третьей всё было бы неплохо на глаз, если бы не это

```
sum = (int) Math.pow(a,2);
```

Для чего вы возводите единицу в квадрат да ещё и таким сложным способом? Почему бы вам просто не написать, что

```
sum = 1;
```

?

И последнее. В первой и последней задаче есть явный счётчик чисел. Нет особого повода делать специальный count. Впрочем, для контроля можно и оставить.

Ну и конечно, в первом решении можно применить подход, использованный в третьей задачке: не умножать каждый раз i, а просто увеличивать sum на два каждый раз. Попробуйте. Подумайте. На то и учебное задание.

**UPD**

```
while(true) {
    if(a <= 10000) {
```

Вот опять же: у вас получился вечный цикл. Ваше приложение зависнет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "cy6erGn0m"

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, оператор break в цикле использовать не желательно.  Во-вторых, откуда числа 333 и 111? В ручную ничего считать не надо.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
            System.out.println("Элемент №" + i + " равен " + (i * 2 + 1));
        }
        System.out.println("Первые " + (i - 1) + " элементов");
    }
}
```

Остальные примеры аналогично.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "DmitryBLR"

Answer (score 2):

В первом примере только за `if(sum == 111)break;` можно двойку ставить, однозначно второй код там берем, хотя и там не понятно, зачем в `for (int i = sum; i <= 54; i++)` sum используется, лучше написать `for (int i = 0; i <= 54; i++)` тогда уж.

Во втором примере вообще непонятно зачем написано `final int second = -90;`

Вместо `for(int i = first; i > second; i-=5)` можно написать `for(int i = first; i > 0; i-=5)` и даже условие `if(i == 0)break;` убрать

В третьем примере вроде все нормально.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "korok"

Answer (score 2):

1 Задание

Во втором коде лишняя переменная `sum` в части `int sum=0;` `for(int i=sum;`
   Ну и цикл от 1 до 55 кажется более читабельным. Вычисление числа при этом будет `2*i-1`

2 Задание

Цикл по заголовку до -90, но реально выход по `break`. Перенести проверку неотрицательности в заголовок цикла

3 Задание

Опять лишние `sum` и `a` до цикла. Дублирование переменных `i` и `count`. "Достаточно одной таблэтки"

Answer (score 0):

Вот так выводит, надо указать предел максимального интовского значения, чтобы зацикливания не было, всё ровно:

```
for (int i = 1, a = -166; i < 2147483647; a = 2 * a + 200, i++) {
    if(a > 9 && a < 100) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```